# SQL Server 2005 mixed mode authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication

just wondering is it possible to use mixed mode on sql server 2005 for user sa? I know how to do this in management studio but this isn't enough for user "sa". I think it needs done else where.

I am trying to connect to the database via a console app but keep getting the error "The account is disabled"

Cheers

Louis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284(v=SQL.90).aspx

How to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670(v=SQL.90).aspx

If you didn't enable Mixed Mode Authentication during setup then you will need to do so in server properties > Security (you can use Management Studio - see above link).  You will also need to enable the sa login and set an appropriate password.

[image: Enable MixedMode]

[image: Enable sa]

Be sure to restart the SQL Service after changing the authentication mode for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I have done it this way and it doesn't work. It doesn't ask me during installation for which authentication mode to use ?

Comment: You've verified that the SERVER has been configured for Mixed Mode (as shown above in the first image) and that the sa login for the server has been enabled as shown in the second image?  You will also need to restart the SQL service for the changes to authentication mode to go into effect.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using SQL Express 2005 or you do not have SQL Server Management Studio installed you will need to update a [registry key to enable Mixed Mode Authentication](http://eduzine.edujini-labs.com/archives/24-HOWTO-Configure-Microsoft-SQL-Server-for-Mixed-Mode-Authentication.html):

> Open registry editor (launch
>   application %WINDIR%\regedit.exe) and
>   go to
>   HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQLServer in the tree
>   on the left.
>
> On the right, look for an entry named
>   LoginMode. The default value, when
>   installed is 1. Update it to 2. The
>   next step is to restart the service.
>
> Launch your Service Manager (Start ->
>   Run -> Type services.msc) and look for
>   a service named MSSQL Server
>   (SQLEXPRESS). Restart the service.

Once the SQL Server service is restarted you then need to enable the sa account. Use the OSQL command line tool from an Administrator Command Prompt:

```
osql -E -S .\SQLEXPRESS
ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE ;
GO
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '<password>' ;
GO
```

You should then be able to test the login using:

```
osql -U sa -S .\SQLEXPRESS
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Express 2005 but I have no `MSSQL.1` branch in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\ just `90` and `SSMEE`

Answer (score 0):

If you SQL Server is already configured for `Mixed Mode Authentication`, then you just need to `enable` the `sa` user.  You can find it in the `Security->Logins` folder.